# Making Apache Xerces support Xpath 2.0

Tags: xerces

I use Apache Xerces 2.11.0, and I'd like to know how to make it support XPath 2.0.

Thanks a lot,
Aviad

Answer (score 0):

There are two sample implementations which use the extension mechanism in Xerces, one standalone, and one for Eclipse:

- [Eclipse PsychoPathXPathProcessor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor)
- [XSLTProcessor+XPath](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltproc/)